# How to play VEVO Content using YouTube iframe API?

Tags: youtube-api, html5-video

I need to play VEVO videos on an HTML5 player which is created using YouTube's API in iOS.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Currently I'm able to play normal videos with out a glitch.But when ever i try to play a VEVO video,It says "The content cant be played outside of YouTube".Is there any legal way of going about this?.

I have already tried to set the "origin" property of the player to my domain.This did not help.

This is an Example from the above link where the origin is set

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If anyone knows of any other way to legally play VEVO content please let me know. :).Any legal loopholes will also do :D.

Comment: Ever figure this out by any chance?

Comment: @nvd90 as capsule pointed out,some contents were restricted by parameters like county,if the owner has allowed it on mobile devices ..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played some vevo videos just by placing the ID.

Sometimes vevo videos have certain restractions for embedding like for example, the country from the user is fetching the video.